# Javascript Audio Play() function not working properly in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, html5-audio

I'm trying to call Javascript Audio Play() function in Microsoft Edge, but it is not working properly, sometimes it works and sometimes not. I tried the same code in Chrome, and Firefox and it works perfectly. Only MS Edge is not stable.

I use mp3 files less than 300 KB clips.

```
 let audioTrack = new Audio(file); 
 audioTrack.preload = 'auto'; 
 console.log(audio file [${file}] length: ${audioTrack.duration} sec.);
 audioTrack.onloadeddata = function () { 
   console.log(audio: ${file} has successfully loaded.); 
}; 
audioTrack.play();
```

Update:
I've updated the tracks list in my code:

```
<script>
    var sounds = new Array(new Audio("http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Heavy-synth-loop-126-bpm.mp3?_=1"),
        new Audio("http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Groove-synth-loop-130-bpm.mp3?_=1"),
        new Audio("http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Mystical-loop-118-bpm.mp3?_=1"),
        new Audio("http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/New-generation-synth-loop-120.mp3?_=1"),
        new Audio("http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Synth-arp-music-loop-118.mp3?_=1"),
        new Audio("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"),
       new Audio("http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2079&type=mp3"),
        new Audio("http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3")
    );
    var i = -1;
    playSnd();

    function playSnd() {
        i++;
        if (i == sounds.length) return;
        sounds[i].onended = playSnd;
        sounds[i].play();
    };
</script>
```

It works fine on Edge but I still don't know why in my application is still not working in a stable way.

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? I have tested the [Audio play() sample](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp) on my side (using Microsoft Edge Chromium (Version 81.0.416.64 (Official build) (64-bit)) and Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0), they all works well. Please check it. If still not working, please try to use F12 developer tools to check if there have any error? and try to clear the browser data and recheck it. Besides, it is better to post enough code or create a sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: My version is "Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363" and if you tried single file it would work, the problem happens when you play sequence of sound clips. You may success to play the first five but after that nothing is played, also there is no code errors show in the console.

Comment: This is sample code of what I wrote:
        let audioTrack = new Audio(file);
        audioTrack.preload = 'auto';
        console.log(`audio file [${file}] length: ${audioTrack.duration} sec.`);

        audioTrack.onloadeddata = function () {
            console.log(`audio: ${file} has successfully loaded.`);
        };

        audioTrack.load();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, I discovered the issue. I use a bootstrap modal before I call the Audio.play(), for some reason this makes the sound fail to play in the Microsoft Edge. So I changed the sequence, I called the modal function then in the 'shown' event I called the Audio.play() method, that made it work (sort of stable).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the console.log command or modify the code as below:

```
<script>
    function play() {
        var file = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-15.mp3'
        let audioTrack = new Audio(file);
        audioTrack.preload = 'auto';
        console.log("audio file " + file + "length:" + audioTrack.duration + "  sec.");
        audioTrack.onloadeddata = function () {
            console.log("audio: " + file + " has successfully loaded."); 
        }; 
        audioTrack.play();
    }
</script>
<button onclick="play()">Play Audio</button>
```

The above code works well on my side (using IE, the legacy version of Microsoft Edge(Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0) and Edge chromium(Version 81.0.416.64 (Official build) (64-bit)) browser)

**Edit**:

To play multiple sound files in sequence using JavaScript, you could refer to the following samples:

sample 1:

```
<script>
    var sounds = new Array(new Audio("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3"),
        new Audio("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3"),
        new Audio("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3"),
        new Audio("http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3")
    );
    var i = -1;
    playSnd();

    function playSnd() {
        i++;
        if (i == sounds.length) return;
        sounds[i].addEventListener('ended', playSnd);
        sounds[i].play();
    };
</script>
```

and [sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9bad2758/1/) (click the play menu in the audio, it will play the multiple sounds in sequence):

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="active"><a href="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-5.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-6.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-7.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-c8.mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3">SoundHelix-Song-9.mp3</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    var audio;
    var playlist;
    var tracks;
    var current;

    init();
    function init() {
        current = 0;
        audio = $('audio');
        playlist = $('#playlist');
        tracks = playlist.find('li a');
        len = tracks.length - 1;
        audio[0].volume = 0.6;
        playlist.find('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            link = $(this);
            current = link.parent().index();
            run(link, audio[0]);
        });
        audio[0].addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
            current++;
            if (current == len) {
                current = 0;
                link = playlist.find('a')[0];
            } else {
                link = playlist.find('a')[current];
            }
            run($(link), audio[0]);
        });
    }
    function run(link, player) {
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: AGAIN, if you are playing once, or one file there will be no issue. Try to put 50 mp3 file in sequence and play them. Also how did you run this code in IE while it doesn't support the Audio API ??

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Web_audio_concepts_and_usage

Comment: The [Audio object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) and the [play() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) are all support IE 11 browser, please check the browser compatibility. Besides, to play multiple sound files in sequence using JavaScript, please refer the above samples.

Comment: Thanks for reply, sample one is more close to what I need, I need to use the "new Audio()" constructor not the <audio> tag, if you create a new object for each clip, then you will reproduce my situation. Note(you are using the same three sample files which are already cached) please load 10 distinct files.

Comment: If using different files, it still works well in Edge browser, please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79RCY.png) (it seems that you have already found it). About your application not working in a stable way. I suggest you could try to set debugger in this part of code and step by step to debug it. You could also check whether you could get the correct audio list and use F12 developer tool to check whether the audio file is load success. Besides, if still not found the real reason, I suggest you could use the sample one as a workaround.